# Expression 'destination' of type 'File' cannot be invoked as a function

Tags: file, kotlin, copy

I am trying to builf a function, that copies all files from a certain directory to a new one, if their extension matched the extension I am passing to the function, and if they are not empty.

I keep getting this error `Expression 'destination' of type 'File' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found`.

I am a bit confused as to how to approach this as `File` can be either a file or a directory correct? SO in my case, I pass a directory to that function, so how do I copy my desired files in to new files in THAT directory? I'm new to handling files.

Here's my code so far (I'd like to just return the amount of files that were copied).

```
fun copyFiles(source: File, destination: File, fileExtension: String = ""): Int {

    var copiedFiles =0;
    if(!source.isDirectory() || !destination.isDirectory() return 0

    source.walk().forEach {file->
        if(file.length().toInt() == 0) return@forEach

        if(fileExtension !="" &&  file.extension !=  fileExtension) return@forEach

        file.copyTo(destination(copiedFiles.toString()))
        copiedFiles++
    }


    return copiedFiles
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are placing brackets after variable name (like you do in `destination(copiedFiles.toString())`), compiler thinks you are trying to invoke `destination` object like a function. In other words it tries to call `invoke` method (you can read about that [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html)) that should exist in any object, that is called like a function. Obviously, `File` class doesn't have it.

May be, you missed some method call? Something like `destination.`**`clone`**`(copiedFiles.toString())` (I don't know what method you really need here).